# Loading Image while WPF Application Startup

Tags: wpf

How to Load an image, showing the application Start up Process ?? Please help me with Appropriate Tutorial.

Exactly what i need is when some one clicks on the Application Icon the Loading Process Image should be displayed showing the progress ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [SplashScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen.aspx).

From the Remarks section in SplashScreen:

> Use the SplashScreen class to show an image in a startup window, or
>   splash screen, when a WPF application starts. Call the Show method to
>   display the splash screen. Call the Close method to close the splash
>   screen. Specify the image to use in the SplashScreen constructor.